# Use a Variable as the URL in a before;httpget request

Tags: marketing-cloud

Instead of hardcoding urls like so:

```
%%before; httpget; 1 "http://www.someurl.com/blog/"%%
```

I'd like to pass variables, from various emails,  into call such as:

```
%%before; httpget; 1 v(@rssUrl)%%
```

No luck in all my attempts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the old method of performing a GET in ExactTarget. Its no longer documented on the site and I believe you should use the new function that is documented [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/). Using the new function `HttpGet()`, you would add variables using `Concat()`.

```
%%=HttpGet(Concat("https://www.google.com/?q=",@variable))=%%
```

However the function in your question is slightly different. I have seen profile attributes called using [square brackets]. Like this:

```
%%httpget ; 0 "https://www.google.com/?q=[profile_attribute]"%%
```

Again this was with profile attributes and not variables, so please test it and comment if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you store all the variables of interest in a Data Extension.  Do a lookup as needed.

Comment: If I was to do that I could do a look up in the httpget for the url?

Comment: You could, sure.  Just do your look up to get the variable name, and pass that into httpget

Comment: I've found how to do that with HTTPGet(@Var)  but not with the example above.